# Android - how to implement android:onClick on a custom view?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have created a custom view, and now I'm implementing DataBinding where I use things like

```
android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.logout(context)}"
```

Similar to where you set the text:

```
  val text = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.StatusButton_android_text)
  textview.text = text
```

I added `<attr name="android:onClick" />` but I'm not sure how to implement the tag

Comment: i think you'd add a callback(onClickListener) programmatically instead of xml android:onClick attribute, it is only able to fetch function defined from parent view's android:context.

Comment: Why are you creating a new onClick method? Every view can already handle clicks.